# Accessing values in Sets within a Map

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I currently have initialized a new Map. And within that Map, I have initialized 3 Sets.

```
myMainMap = [disk:[], build:[], commits:[]]
```

I have a function which gets certain values from git and the output looks like:

```
rev = 97sdf9s7fs7896fs0d7fs0
remoteUrl = ssh://git@my-repo:5000/test/project
branch = (7s8a6)
```

This is then added to the Set `commits` in `myMainMap`

```
def commitInfo = [repository: remoteUrl, commit: rev, branch: branch]
myMainMap['commits'].add(commitInfo)
```

So now `myMainMap` looks like :

```
[images:[], buildEnv:[], commits:[[commit:97sdf9s7fs7896fs0d7fs0, repository:ssh://git@my-repo:5000/test/project, branch:(7s8a6)]]]
```

Now I need to extract the value of `commit`, `repository` and `branch` from this `Set` which is **inside** a Map and then run an `assert` on those values.

I can run an assert this way :

```
assert myMainMap.containsValue([[commit:"97sdf9s7fs7896fs0d7fs0", repository:"ssh://git@my-repo:5000/test/project", branch:"(7s8a6)"]])
```

but this is an assert on the Set rather than the individual values of keys.
Also this only works if key values are inside `""` rather than `[]`

So what would be the most efficient way to extract the values of keys inside a Set which is inside a Map ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the last line of the below snippet. It does the check you want using only `rev`.

`myMainMap.commits*.commit` gives you a List of all the `rev` hashes.

This spread operator feature of groovy is explained [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_spread_operator)

```
def myMainMap = [disk:[], build:[], commits:[]]

def rev = '97sdf9s7fs7896fs0d7fs0'
def remoteUrl = 'ssh://git@my-repo:5000/test/project'
def branch = '(7s8a6)'

def commitInfo = [repository: remoteUrl, commit: rev, branch: branch]
myMainMap.commits.add(commitInfo)

//below line does the contains check in your commit list inside the map
assert myMainMap.commits*.commit.contains('97sdf9s7fs7896fs0d7fs0')
```